# android layout textview between two button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have comman header with two button and single textview.
textview is in center of the screen. button 1 is at the right side of the parent and button2 is at the left side of the parent.

now, I want to show text  view in the center of the parent not in the center of the space between two buttons.

Text length in the textview can be any thing either it could be 3 words or it could be more than 10 word.

**I dont want to overlap textview above the two buttons while length is more than 10 words.
and also I want textview in the center of the screen while there is only 3 words.**

**When I am using below code it is not showing textview in the center of the screen horizontally when there is only 3 to 4 words but below code also dont overlap while there is more than 10 words.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Webviewdemo" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/backbtn" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/infobtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="123"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**In same way  When I am using below code it is  showing textview in the center of the screen horizontally when there is only 3 to 4 words but below code  overlap while there is more than 10 words.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Webviewdemo" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/backbtn" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/infobtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="123"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, My question is how can I achive above both thing with single code.

1. Textview should not overlap while there is more words.
2. Textview should be in center while there is less no of words.

I hope you all get my problem. if any query plz ask.

Comment: Can you please provide a screen model of what is happening now and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Just remove the singleLine element from textview.

Comment: I cant remove bcoz it is header and in header I have show heading in single line

Comment: Please give snap we can get want you exactly want.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/panelIconLeft1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnHome1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="LOCATION"
        android:onClick="btnHomeClick" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtHeading1"
  style="@style/heading_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/panelIconRight1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/panelIconLeft1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/panelIconRight1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFeedback1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Post Ad"
        android:onClick="btnFeedbackClick" />
</LinearLayout
```

> The above code will help you

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="123"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>
```

**EDIT**
remove this line

```
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Comment: see my first code. I have tried above code but its not showing in center of the screen. when there is length is 3 of 4.

Comment: see my code `android:layout_width="match_parent"`. You are using `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

```
   Use This Code 

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="left">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: text view in center what u want tell again give Screen shoot i will slove

Answer (score 0):

try this (without `centerInParent`)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="123"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>
```